# Align react table to centre of page

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a table in react and struggling to centre it to the page, so that it sits under the drop-down select and Title

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-forked-uo9sc?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: This seems like it should be solvable using any of the standard CSS centring techniques (e.g. `margin: 0 auto;`)

Comment: You can also wrap your table in `div` and apply style as `display:flex` & `justify-content:center`. There are many ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin: auto;` to your StyledTable, like so:

```
const StyledTable = styled.table`
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
  `;
```

Comment: Knew it would be something simple :-D - thanks